# python-flask handling application errors

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, exception

I've built a flask application and I try to catch unhandled application errors from my routes using the errorhandler decorator.

I've a main.py which looks like this,

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Ping, '/ping')

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    print "caught internal server error"
    return "This page does not exist", 500
```

The route Ping is in another file, here is a sample version of the file

```
class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self):

        raise
        return {}, 200
```

I've placed a raise to try and reproduce a 500 Internal server error. Here is a sample error raised by my application

```
[2019-01-26 10:37:36,449] ERROR in app: Exception on /events/v1/monitoring/ping [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myapi/ping.py", line 17, in get
    raise
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2019 10:37:36] "GET /ping HTTP/1.0" 500 -
```

For reasons I haven't been able to figure, the @app.errorhandler decorator doesn't catch any 500 error that come are raised by the application.

Comment: What is the value of 'DEBUG' in your Flask app's config?

Comment: its the default value, False

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are using *flask-restful*. In order to your error handler be catched you should set the config param `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` to `True` in your config file.

Flask restful has its own error handler which differs from that of Flask. This is an extract:

```
[...]

if not isinstance(e, HTTPException) and current_app.propagate_exceptions:
    exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    if exc_value is e:
        raise
    else:
        raise e

headers = Headers()
if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
    code = e.code
    default_data = {
        'message': getattr(e, 'description', http_status_message(code))
    }
    headers = e.get_response().headers
else:
    code = 500
    default_data = {
        'message': http_status_message(code),
    }
[...]
```

After setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` to `True` you should add at least these two error handlers:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return jsonify({'msg': 'Internal server error'}), 500

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error_500(e):
    return jsonify({'msg': 'Internal server error'}), 500
```

So, the first one will catch any exception raised at application level, even your own custom exceptions and the second one will catch any 500 error, for example raised on `abort(500)`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using flask-restful
Once I set the config, do you know how to catch all 500 Internal server errors and gracefully deal with them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one instead:

```py
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
```

Comment: In my application I have multiple errorhandlers. One for the general exception case, just as Александр has done here. Then a few additional handlers for 500, 403, 404, etc.. Maybe you will have better luck using both?