# Python error handling for flask expects json module throws internal server error

Tags: python, validation, flask

I am using the flask_expects_json library to validate the JSON schema in API requests.

This is working, however, when a request is not valid, the error is thrown in the logs but the details of the error message are not returned by the API. The response is just a generic message "Internal Server Error".

Error message:

```
{"event": "Exception on /ingest [PUT]", "logger": "app", "level": "error", "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_expects_json/__init__.py\", line 30, in decorated_function\n    validate(data, schema)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py\", line 934, in validate\n    raise error\njsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'location' is a required property\n\nFailed validating 'required' in schema}
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Question: How do I handle the errors from flask_expects_json and return the details of the error instead of the server error? In other words, I need the details of the error in the response, such as:

```
{
    "error": "'location' is a required property"
}
```

Here is the code I have so far.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, current_app
from flask_restx import Resource, Api
from flask_expects_json import expects_json

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='Test API', description='Test API Description')

  @api.route('/ingest', endpoint="ingest", methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
  class Ingest(Resource):
    @expects_json(test_schema)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # logic removed for brevity
      result = get_result()
      return result

  return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I also tried writing an error handler to catch these errors as per the [flask documentation on error handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/) and other [similar Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377654/python-flask-handling-application-errors) but it does not appear to be doing anything.

```
class BadRequest(Exception):
  status_code = 400

  def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
    Exception.__init__(self)
    self.message = message
    if status_code is not None:
      self.status_code = status_code
    self.payload = payload

  def to_dict(self):
    rv = dict(self.payload or ())
    rv['message'] = self.message
    return rv

  @app.errorhandler(BadRequest)
  def handle_bad_request(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

UPDATE: This error is probably caused by the gunicorn structlog configuration that is attempting to convert a ValidationError to JSON and failing therefore throwing the 500 error.

Here is the gunicorn.conf.py

```
import structlog
import os
from datetime import datetime

if os.environ.get('ENV') == 'development':
  reload = True

hostname = os.uname().nodename
timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

pre_chain = [
    structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
    structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
    structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
    structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
    structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
    structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
    structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt='iso', utc=True),
]

logconfig_dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "json_formatter": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
            "foreign_pre_chain": pre_chain,
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "error_console": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "json_formatter",
            "filename": "/home/logs/error_console_{}_{}.log".format(hostname, timestamp),
            "mode": "a"
        },
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "json_formatter",
            "filename": "/home/logs/console_{}_{}.log".format(hostname, timestamp),
            "mode": "a"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        'gunicorn.error': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.environ.get('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.environ.get('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the 500 error that is occurring when it attempts to throw the 400 Bad Request error but then runs into a TypeError. `TypeError: Object of type ValidationError is not JSON serializable`.

```
Failed validating 'required' in schema
   
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ValidationError is not JSON serializable
```

UPDATE 2 [WORKAROUND]: As mentioned I think this issue is due to an error handling issue when expects_json throws a ValidationError. It might be related to the gunicorn structlog config or it might be something that can be fixed in the expects_json library. As a workaround I removed expects_json and created a custom decorator to validate the json schema using the jsonschema library similar to the accepted answer in this related question. [Flask: Decorator to verify JSON and JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238743/flask-decorator-to-verify-json-and-json-schema)

Here is the full code of my solution. Again this does not actually solve the issue directly but is an acceptable workaround and does provide a bit more control.

```
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response, current_app
import os, json, jsonschema

def validate_json_schema(schema_name):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

      basedir = current_app.config['BASE_DIR']
      jsonmodelsdir = basedir + '/jsonmodels'

      if not request.json:
        error_msg = "Missing JSON data."
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'invalidRequest', 'message': error_msg}), 400)

      try:
        with open('{}/{}.json'.format(jsonmodelsdir, schema_name)) as json_file:
          json_model = json.load(json_file)
      except Exception as e:
        error_msg = "Server error: Unable to get json model."
        current_app.logger.error(error_msg)
        current_app.logger.error(e)
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'unavailable', 'message': error_msg}), 500)

      try:
        jsonschema.validate(request.json, json_model)
      except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        error_msg = "Invalid JSON format: {}".format(e)
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'invalidRequest', 'message': error_msg}), 400)
      except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
        error_msg = "Invalid JSON schema: {}".format(e)
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'invalidRequest', 'message': error_msg}), 400)
      except Exception as e:
        error_msg = "Server error: Unable to validate json model."
        current_app.logger.error(e)
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'unavailable', 'message': error_msg}), 500)

      return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
  return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running flask in debug mode ?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes, no difference though. To clarify I want to catch the detail of the validation error and return it in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an example for flask_expects_json error handling: https://pypi.org/project/flask-expects-json/

My answer here expands on that documentation to further clarify how to do this,

imports

```
from flask import make_response, jsonify
from flask_expects_json import expects_json
from jsonschema import ValidationError
```

example schema

```
schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'data': {'type': 'string', "minLength": 31}
    },
    'required': ['data']
}
```

example error handling logic

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    if isinstance(error.description, ValidationError):
        original_error = error.description
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': original_error.message}), 400)
    # handle other "Bad Request"-errors
    return error
```

example post endpoint

```
@app.post("/temp")
@expects_json(schema)
def temp_post():
    if request.is_json:
        request_json = request.get_json()
        data = request_json.get("data")
        return make_response(jsonify({"data_sent": data}), 200)
```

When calling this endpoint with a JSON object that does **not** have the key "data" the following error message will return

```
{
    "error": "'data' is a required property"
}
```

(Maybe those examples did not exist when this question was originally asked)